# Does the compiler optimize the second condition in "for" statement?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, optimization

I wish to iterate through a vector by index, then I have:

```
for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i)
{...}
```

I know using iterator to visit through is more effective, but I just wish to discuss in technical point on compiler optimization.

My question is does this "v.size()" execute only once or multiple times?

Or, the compiler will help me to decide whether the size need to be calculated once enough, or need to be called multiple times, by any optimizing strategy--so that I don't have to:

```
size_t s=v.size()
for(size_t i=0;i<s;++i)
```

to make the code a bit more efficient?

Comment: There are no guarantees. The standard does not require a compiler to do so, nor does it prohibit it from doing so. So it completely depends on your compiler. You'll have to verify it by checking the disassembly. Or simply trust that it does the right thing.

Comment: My experience is that it runs everytime.

Comment: In general, if you want to see what the optimizer will do, go to [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org) and enter your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is does this "v.size()" execute only once or multiple times?

It is executed multiple times, every time the the loop body finishes executing, to check if it should execute again or not.

The compiler might or might not optimize the code without calling `size()` multiple times, it just depends on the compiler.

If the compiler can guarantee that you are not modifying `v` in the loop, then yes, it is entirely possible that the compiler will optimize it. If it can't, then it probably (if it does, then the compiler is bad) won't and *can't* optimize it, as the compiler would then generate code that does something entirely different then what you wrote.

Also, even if the compiler doesn't optimize it away, you'll maybe save 1 or 2 CPU cycles, which is really nothing. `size()` is `O(1)`, calling it shouldn't do anything else than returning a member variable from the vector. Don't optimize prematurely.